# How to open merge request for gitlab in xcode?

Tags: xcode, gitlab

From  v13 xcode has gained some features for source control. One of these features is reviewing pull requests inside xcode. This feature works with github and bitbucket. But with gitlab there is no option in xcode to create merge request and add reviews.

Does gitlab supports this feature? Or is there any settings to enable it?